# Circuit to tell Microcontroller when Voltage is Low

Tags: voltage, batteries, circuit-design

I would like to trip an input, similar to a button input to an microcontroller if the input voltage to the circuit/microcontroller is below a certain threshold. I have transistors and some zener diodes of different voltages but I am not sure how to connect them in order for the microcontroller to get an input when the voltage is below "x" volts.

Comment: Your microcontroller should have a brownout circuit built into it already. It also probably has an ADC with internal reference you can just use to measure the supply voltage, stepping it down first through a resistive divider (and possibly buffering it with an op-amp voltage follower).

Comment: Which microcontroller are you using?

Comment: I am using the GPC11512C

Comment: @VikramBhat wow, that is one exotic microcontroller!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care much about accuracy, you can use a circuit like the below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fngLmS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This circuit uses the Vbe of the transistor as a crude reference and thus has a threshold of around 4V. It's crude, has a mushy transfer function and will vary from unit-to-unit and with temperature.

If you replace R1 with a resistor + zener and pick the value of R2 to pass a properly selected current through the zener you'll get a more consistent threshold of about 0.7V + zener voltage, but zeners less than about 5V have very mushy knees, so it won't be as much of an improvement as you might expect. You could consider replacing the zener + resistor with a green LED + resistor, but it would require some experimentation. It's also possible to use a TL431 with a transistor and some resistors.

If you need something accurate that doesn't drift much with temperature, have a look at supply voltage supervisor chips which contain a reference and a comparator (and sometimes a timer).

Answer (score 1):

The [datasheet](https://d4u-datasheet.netdna-ssl.com/pdf-down/G/P/C/GPC11512C-Generalplus.pdf) of your microcontroller shows no ADC input. Which probably means it's a very, very cheap microcontroller and you're using it for cost reasons.

I'm going to jump in and say: whatever you do (for example, the voltage threshold circuit Spehro describes in his answer, or anything else) will probably cost some money: additional parts, and even worse, additional PCB space and additional steps in manufacturing.

So, replace your GPC11512C by something that has a voltage supervisor and/or an ADC. The additional cents you invest in the microcontroller will be more than compensated by saving the need for an external semiconductor circuit!